# html5 and css link interferance

Tags: html, css

I am a novice at this(css) and I am messing around trying to build a small website with html and css. I am having aa issue where on my page to the left I have my links to external pages. And in the middle of my page I have a paragraph in a section but this paragraph seems to interfere with my links. some of the links wont let me click on them.

This is my css, Can sombody tell me what I am doing wrong here please?

```
body  {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

header {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

section {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 70px;
  left: 0; 
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 3em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  list-style-image: url(download.png);
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: Would love to help but I would need to see the html. Can you put all your code on codepen or jsfiddle? It's most likely the position: absolute causing it.

Comment: ty for the responce here is the cp  http://codepen.io/rt133/pen/gLRVVW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/davidatthepark/pen/jVLNbv?editors=1100

Check out my link above. I put the borders in just so you can visualize what is going on. I'm sure you guessed it already but the `section` was covering the `nav`. A good way to put elements side by side is to use `display: inline-block`. Make sure to look up the `display` selector because it is crucial to writing CSS. All I did was make the width of the `nav` 30%, the `section` to 65% so that they don't flow over 100%, and then give both of them `display: inline-block`. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: ty so much one more question can i move the paragraph in the sectio nu a little so its more in the middle?

Comment: Sure, just play with the width percentages till you get it where you want. I changed my codepen a bit if you want to take a look. Also, please check my answer correct if it was helpful. Let me know if you have more questions. Sorry I replied so late!

Comment: may i ask you something else? this is my new updated pen http://codepen.io/rt133/pen/zoRKrq

Comment: i was wondering how i could move my paragraphs up more and the video i have on the side to go down twoards the midle but still on the right side?